# Passing a value/values outside of for loop to a variable - java :: processing

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, processing, multiset

I am looking how to pass the value word and its corresponding count to be saved into a variable outside the `for` loop. My code is currently:

```
import java.util.Iterator; 
import java.util.*;


import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMultiset; 
import com.google.common.collect.Multiset; 
import com.google.common.collect.Multisets; 

ImmutableMultiset<String> top = null;

void setup() { 
   size(800, 480); 
   smooth(); 

   String[] data = loadStrings("data/data.txt");

   ImmutableMultiset<String> myMultiset = ImmutableMultiset.copyOf(data); 

   top = Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(myMultiset); 

   Iterator it = top.entrySet().iterator(); 

   for (int i = 0; (i < 5) && it.hasNext(); i++) { 
      Multiset.Entry entry = (Multiset.Entry) it.next(); 

      String word = (String) entry.getElement(); 
      int count = entry.getCount(); 

      System.out.println(word + " -> " + count);
   }
}
```

I need these values to apply them to a bar chart in my `draw()` function.

Comment: declare the variable outside the loop's scope.  Then they will persist after the loop finishes.

Comment: You take the 5 first words and counts. How do you want to set this in _one_ variable as suggested in an answer? don't you need the 5?

Comment: Yeah 5 variables or into a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the variables in your class and not locally in your enhanced loop.

e.g.

```
private String word;
private int count;
```

and use getters to call them

e.g.

```
public String getWord(){ return word; }
```

Comment: @Nebbyyy No problem. Mark this answer as helpful and have fun.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Murat's answer, this is a matter of variable scoping. Anything declared within the for loop block (between the {} bounds) will only be visible within this block.

If you declare the count variable outside the for loop block, you will be able to use it within the scope of the block that contains the for loop; in this case the *setup* method.

Murat's example will allow you to obtain the value of this variable from anywhere, whether it's within this or some other class.